# How to populate a field based on selection in previous field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multiple-select

In the form that we designed, we have a "States" field that allows its users to select multiple states at a time. There is a "City" field which should be populated as per the selection in the "State" field. The values in the "City" field are correctly populated if only one state is selected. However, it is not showing correctly when multiple states are selected.

Please suggest a Ruby solution for the same.

Comment: Please post the code for what you have so far.

Comment: Following is the code for the US State  select

<%= select_tag 'usa[states][]', options_from_collection_for_select(state, :state, :state, nil), :multiple => true, :class=>"multi_select" %> 

i use observe field (AJAX) to observe that which state is selected
<%= observe_field :usa_states_ , :url =>{:controller=>"logins",:action =>'deliverable_cities', :id=>'1'}, :update=> 'deliverable_city' , :with => "' state='+document.getElementById('usa_states_').value+'&type=restaurant'", :on=>'click'   %>
upon which state is selected all the cities of that State will be shown in the City select list

Comment: This is working fine when i select only one state. But when i select more than one state i get only one value through ajax hence get only Cities of that single state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `:with` expression in your `observe_field`. `document.getElementById('usa_states_').value` will only return a single value and not all the selected values.

I'm not sure if there is a way to handle this automatically in Rails but one solution is to write a JavaScript function which will build a string of all the selected values separated by commas. e.g.

```
function selectedValuesAsString(multiselect) {
    selectedValues = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < multiselect.length; i++) {
        if (multiselect[i].selected) {
            selectedValues.push(multiselect[i].value);
        }
    }
    return selectedValues.join();
}
```

and then update the `:with` to be something like:

```
:with => "'state='+selectedValuesAsString(document.getElementById('usa_states_')"
```

and then finally split the values inside your controller action.